# Elementary proofs of prime gap theorems?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

"Obviously" it is thrue that $p_{n+1}<2p_n$. Testing for $n<10$ shows it is true for small $n$ and no mathematician or wannabe has ever doubt that it is true for big $n$. But there is no real simple arithmetic proof, so far, not using the prime number theorem or other results that isn't simple to prove.

So I wonder, are there any (non trivial) prime gap theorems at all with simple proofs? Or prime recursion inequalities of the form $p_{n+1}<f(p_1,p_2,\dots,p_n)$?

> Can you prove: $p_{n+1}<p_n^2$ without using PNT, Bertrand's
>   postulate,..?
>
> Can you find a refinement of  $\displaystyle p_{n+1}\le\prod^n_{i=1}p_i+1$, about just as simple to prove?

Comment: The original argument of Chebyshev is a little complicated, but "elementary" and does not use PNT. A much simplified proof was given by Erdos. Please see the Wikipedia article on Bertrand's postulate.

Comment: See Vinogradov's *Elements of Number Theory* for a proof that for any $\varepsilon > 0$, there is an $n$ for which $p_{n+1} < (1 + \varepsilon)p_n$. https://archive.org/details/ElementsOfNumberTheory

Comment: That doesn't answer the question though

Comment: Prime gap theorems with simple proofs - I'm pretty sure that there is a simple proof for "a prime between $n$ and $2n$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$".

Comment: In any case, your terminology of "non trivial" and "simple" is primarily opinion-based. In my opinion, for example, a theorem is trivial if and only if it has a simple proof. So the answer to your question is *No* by definition.

Comment: I don't understand how quotation marks make the initial claim less ... well, what it is.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: it marks a kind of false induction.

Comment: It just signals that the premise of your question is simply untenable, really. II would love to see any basis for the claim that no mathematician has ever doubted the truth of Bertrand's postulate (and the opinion of whatever it is you call wannabes is surely irrelevant? Is there any need to even use that derogatory term at all?)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: I could remove the rhetoric, but I want to communicate a feeling...

Comment: Can we count Euclid's argument that $p_{n+1} \le\prod_{i=1}^n p_i +1$ as a prime-gap-theorem?

Comment: @Neil: yes, it's a good example. Perhaps I should have wrote recursive inequality or something, but are there any refinements then?.

Comment: @barakmanos But the identity between "trivial" and "has simple proof" may not extend to "obvious". For example, everybody$^{\text{TM}}$ considers Jordan's curve theorem *obvious* until they attempt to find a simple proof.

Comment: @Lehs You can easily create a condition dependent solely on the previous prime itself if you like: $p_{n+1} \le\prod_{i=1}^n p_i +1 \le p_n^n +1 \le p_n^{p_n} +1$

Comment: @Neil: yes, few arguments is preferable, but "good" estimates with elementary proofs are what I desire.

Answer (score 2):

For the question about $p_{k+1} < p_k^2$, this should be fairly easy to deduce from the estimate $\sum_{\text{$p$ prime, }p \leq n} \frac{\ln p}{p} = \ln n + O(1)$, so long as you're careful to make the $O(1)$ bound explicit. The proof of the estimate is elementary and short. (See the exercises to Chapter 2 of Vinogradov's *Elements of Number Theory*.)

Namely, if the $O(1)$ term is between $A$ and $B$, then as long as $n > e^{B-A}$, there must be a prime between $n$ and $n^2$. Then you can check small values of $n$ manually.

I haven't worked out the details of what $A$ and $B$ are, but I don't think they're large.

Edit: Here is a [quick proof](http://web.williams.edu/Mathematics/lg5/mertens.pdf) of Mertens' estimate, which is what we used above. On  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens%27_theorems) it is stated that $O(1)$ is bounded by $2$ in absolute value, so this would establish the theorem for all $n > e^4$.

This proof can be immediately generalized to prove that if $n$ is large enough, then there is necessarily a prime number between $n$ and $n^{1 + \varepsilon}$.

Answer (score 0):

There is a refinement of  $\displaystyle p_{n+1}\le\prod^n_{i=1}p_i+1$, just about as simple to prove:

$ \displaystyle
p_n\leq 2\prod_{q\in\Bbb P'}^{q<p_n}q+1$, where 
$\Bbb P'=\{p\in\Bbb P|\exists m\in\Bbb N:p=4m+3\}$and $n>3$.

*Proof*: Let $ \displaystyle
A_n=2\prod_{q\in\Bbb P'}^{q<p_n}q+1$ and suppose $p_n>A_n$. Then $A_n$ only has prime factors $p_k<p_n$ such that $p_k=4m+1,\; m\in\Bbb N$. Thus $A_n=4m'+1,\; m\in\Bbb N$ which is obviously not true.
Hence $p_n\leq A_n$.

A simple proof for the corresponding conjecture with $\Bbb P''=\{p\in\Bbb P|\exists m\in\Bbb N:p=4m+1\}$ is probably also possible and it might be possible to show for any similar class of primes for $n$ big enough.